# how can solve the ReferenceError: window is not defined in service-worker at pwa?

Tags: manifest, progressive-web-apps

> ReferenceError: window is not defined

progressive web apps using at "add to home screen" not working.
this is my services-workder.js

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function(e) {
e.userChoice.then(function(choiceResult){
    console.log(choiceResult.outcome);
    if(choiceResult.outcome == 'dismissed'){
        console.log('User cancelled home screen install');
    }else{
        console.log('User added to home screen');
    }
});});
```

Answer (score 1):

That code is meant to run in the context of your web app's `window`, not inside of your service worker's code.

So, move it to something like a `<script>` tag inside of your HTML.